# jQuery Tablesorter plugin - sortable headers not working

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

Ive been working on making my Tabes sortable and stumbled on tablesorter.

So I install it and follow the [Documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html#Introduction)

Sadly I fail at the first step and dont know why.

Heres my scripts in the head tag:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <script src="components/com_memberportal/events/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/com_memberportal/events/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) { 
            $("table") 
                .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
                .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 

            $("#EventTable").tablesorter(); 
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
```

The paths are correct I checked that. So heres my table:

```
         <table id="EventTable" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Speaker</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <?php 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchresult)):

                    $date = explode("-", $row['event_date']);
                    $time_gone = explode(" ", $date[2]);
                    $date_table = $time_gone[0] . "." . $date[1] . "." . $date[0];  
                ?>   
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $date_table;?></td>               
                    <td><?php echo $row['event_type_name'];?></td>

                    <?php 
                        $UserLink = "https://www.myhost.com/website/index.php?option=com_memberportal&view=profile&" . $row['firstname'] . "-" . $row['lastname'];
                        echo '<td><a href="' . $UserLink . '">', $row['firstname'], " " ,$row['lastname'] . '</a></td>';

                        $EventLink = "https://www.myhost.com/website/index.php?option=com_memberportal&view=event&" . $row['event_date'] . "&" . $row['event_subject'];
                        echo '<td><a href="' . $EventLink . '">', $row['event_subject'] . '</a></td>';

                    ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Basically I have a table listing events with 4 columns (date, type, speaker, subject).

All the information in the table is from my mysql database. I know that its a hardcoded table in the documentation but I assumed it would still work with mine, as long as I wrap the right tags around the right parts.

Anybody know what Im doing wrong?

Edit: A picture of my html table

[image]

Comment: That javascript code needs to be in its own seperate `<script></script>` tag

Comment: @kerbholz Oh man stupid mistake. Thanks! I now put it in a seperate tag. But it still doesnt work. Ill update the code to reflect what it looks like now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the added rows are all wrapped in their own `<tbody>` - you can't sort individual rows. Make the loop only add `<tr>`s. Something like this:

```
<tbody>
<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchresult)):

    $date = explode("-", $row['event_date']);
    $time_gone = explode(" ", $date[2]);
    $date_table = $time_gone[0] . "." . $date[1] . "." . $date[0];  
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $date_table;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event_type_name'];?></td>

    <?php 
        $UserLink = "https://www.myhost.com/website/index.php?option=com_memberportal&view=profile&" . $row['firstname'] . "-" . $row['lastname'];
        echo '<td><a href="' . $UserLink . '">', $row['firstname'], " " ,$row['lastname'] . '</a></td>';

        $EventLink = "https://www.myhost.com/website/index.php?option=com_memberportal&view=event&" . $row['event_date'] . "&" . $row['event_subject'];
        echo '<td><a href="' . $EventLink . '">', $row['event_subject'] . '</a></td>';

    ?>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</tbody>
```

Secondly, the original tablesorter is no longer being actively maintained. If you still want to use tablesorter, try my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which you can drop in to replace without any changes in the javascript.

I would suggest combining the initialization code and using `$(function(){...});` as newer versions of jQuery do not support the document ready format.

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $("table") 
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 

    $("#EventTable").tablesorter(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! It seems to work now, but Im not sure. When I try to sort it just empties my table. I assume thats because I didnt tell it what to sort by? Or is it supposed to sort by some default? Ill update my code so you can see what it looks like now

Comment: It shouldn't be emptying the table. Can you share what the rendered HTML looks like? Include the pager and yes, you will need to set the parser (`header` option, or class name in the header) for the date column if it isn't in a `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: I added a picture of the rendered HTML table and as you can see in my code I included the pager. Where would I need to set the parser? The formats in my table are datetime/string/string/string

Comment: Use the [`dateFormat` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#dateformat).